# How to install packages on a conda environment with a specific python version

Tags: python-3.x, package, conda, environment

I need to use opencv and it needed python version older than 3.9. So I created a conda environment with python 3.7.9 and tried to use
`pip install opencv-python`
It installed but when I tried to import it gave an error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

After I installed it on the anaconda environments tab I could import. I need to install pylibdmtx, too, but again I cannot import it after installing.

I see the version of python is 3.7.9 on the environment. But when I use pip it is using this:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.9)`

I do not know what I am missing here. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

### Recommended Solution

Prefer specifying what you want in an environment up front, e.g.,

**opencv.yaml**

```yaml
name: py37_opencv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - opencv
```

**Create Environment**

```bash
conda env create -n py37_opencv -f opencv.yaml
```

### Troubleshooting Issue

Otherwise, if you want get the version you have working, try ensuring that `pip` is actually installed in the environment of interest:

```bash
conda activate your_env
conda install pip
# then use pip …
```